# Java regular expression for matching filenames or filetypes

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, match

I am trying to write a java regular expression where my application should restrict the names of the files or filetypes mentioned in the regex from being attached to an email. I started the regex like this,

```
    .*\\.(?:jpeg|jpg)$.
```

Is this correct?. Right now it is not working(matching). Also, how can I add new file types or filenames to this expression incase if I want to expand this regex. Like say, I want to add the vcf file types also here in this regex, how should I do that? Also, If I need to add the filenames, say abc.bmp from being attached, how and where should I include that filename in this regex?. Any help is greatly appreciated as I am new to this regex.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are using it?

Comment: What do you use for send mail? Is this a web application or Swing o SWT application?

Answer (score 3):

what about

```
if (fileName.endsWith(".jpg") || fileName.endsWith(".jpeg")) {
    // good
} else {
    // bad
}
```

I read your comment under m.buttners answer and propose the following:

```
List<String> allowedExtensions = loadExtensionsFromConfig(); // implement this
boolean isFileAllowed = false;
for (String extension : allowedExtensions) {
    if (fileName.endsWith(extension)) { // this is case sensitive!
        isFileAllowed = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like this:

```
.*\\.(jpe?g)$
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not matching is simply the `.` at the end. This tries to match a character **after** the end of the string. That, obviously, can't work. Remove it, and you should be fine. Note that you can reduce `(?:jpeg|jpg)` to `jpe?g`.

This is not saying that a regex is the right approach to this problem. I prefer jlordo's approach, as long as there is only a small amount of possible file extensions. This is just to let you know where you went wrong with the regex.

Note that either `.*` or `$` is redundant. If you are using `match` it requires the pattern to match the entire string anyway. In that case you don't need to assert `$` again. If you use `find`, then you don't need to match parts of the the string that are arbitrary anyway, so you can leave out the `.*`.

**EDIT:**

After the discussion in the comments, if you have a set of allowed extensions, plus a set of allowed specific file names, this would be the general regular expression:

```
^(?:.*\\.(?:all|allowed|file|extensions)|all\\.allowed|file\\.names)$
```

Comment: I can't use jlordo's approach here because there is no specific set of file types that I know in advance. This is going to be a configurable regex which will be used by the clients(users) to mention the filenames or the file types that they want to filter. My java code should get that configurable regex from properties file and match the current filename or filetype with the regex to check if there is any matching. I am using $ here to denote the end of line. So now If I need to add any more file extensions(bmp,vcf..) or file names(abc.txt), Can you tell me the format that I need to follow?.

Comment: @user1867196 Something like `^(?:.*\\.(?:all|allowed|file|extensions)|all\\.allowed|file\\.names)$`, I suppose?

Comment: @user1867196 please consider accepting the answer to show future visitors that (and how) your problem has been solved